Regex does not work properly with chinese characters on applescript
I'm trying to make a script that parse current folder into usable parts, following by pattern (\d\d\d\.\d+.\d+) - (.*)(\(.*)\) in python, which captures 3 groups {date, name, person} (date is in format of mine country so it's not in yyyymmdd)
However the regex works poorly when chinese char is within name.
For example:
111.1.1 - this_is_file_name(cookie) => {"111.1.1", "this_is_file_name", "cookie"}
111.1.1 - 檔案(cookie) => {"111.1.1", "檔", "案"} # this acts really weird
this is the script I'm running, might be a bit different since applescript syntax is different from python version regex.
-- Extract filename and person from current folder name using regex
set regexPattern to "(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+)\\s-\\s(.*)(\\(.*\\))?$"
set {dateString, name, person} to extractData(currentolderPath, regexPattern)

display alert dateString # working as intended
display alert name # bad value
display alert person # bad value

-- Extract data using regex
on extractData(inputString, regexPattern)
    try
        set capturedData to {}
        set regexResults to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of inputString & " | grep -oE '" & regexPattern & "'"
        set {rocDateString, filename, person} to words of regexResults
        set capturedData to {rocDateString, filename, person}
    on error
        set capturedData to {"", "", ""}
    end try
    return capturedData
end extractData



Three things…
First, avoid using name as a variable as it already has meaning in various places. You can see that its colour is different than the other variables (on my system it is coloured purple, like a property, rather than green like a variable. Try something like fName instead.
Second, the key cause of your issue is words.
If you run the following line in a separate script, you will see the issue:
words of "111.1.1 - 檔案(cookie)"
--> {"111.1.1", "檔", "案", "cookie"}

To the system, each of the two Chinese characters are individually considered a word. Additionally, the () are considered punctuation and not parts of the word cookie. I should note that depending upon your system environment (mine is set to US English), you may get a different result.
The outcome is that when you ask for the first three words of the string, you don't get cookie.
Will your input string always have the same structure?
eg 'datestring' ' - ' 'chinese characters' 'word in parentheses'
Updates:
Try this. Instead of using grep and words (which may not apply depending upon the input string), I use sed and paragraphs. The sed command breaks the string into paragraphs based on each capturing group. Each of the three variables can then be assigned the appropriate group.
Update: Revise script to properly handle both inputString and currentFolderPath, per comments/image
set inputString to quoted form of "113.1.29 - 一段文字(123)"
set currentFolderPath to "/Users/cookie/Desktop/113.10.10 - helloworld測試(test)"

set regexCmd to "sed -Ee 's@^.*\\/([[:digit:]]+\\.[[:digit:]]+\\.[[:digit:]].*$)@\\1@' -e 's@([[:digit:]]+\\.[[:digit:]]+\\.[[:digit:]]+)[[:blank:]]-[[:blank:]](.*)(\\(.*\\))@\\1\\
\\2\\
\\3@ ' "

-- filename, person
set {inputDateString, inputFileName, inputPerson} to extractData(inputString, regexCmd)
display alert "Date string: " & inputDateString # working as intended
display alert "File name: " & inputFileName # bad value
display alert "Person: " & inputPerson # bad value

log "inputString: " & inputString & linefeed & "inputDateString: " & inputDateString & linefeed & "inputFileName: " & inputFileName & linefeed & "inputPerson: " & inputPerson & linefeed


-- folder path
set currentFolderPath to quoted form of currentFolderPath
set {folderDateString, folderFileName, folderPerson} to extractData(currentFolderPath, regexCmd)

log "currentFolderPath: " & currentFolderPath & linefeed & "folderDateString: " & folderDateString & linefeed & "folderFileName: " & folderFileName & linefeed & "folderPerson: " & folderPerson

-- handler
on extractData(inputString, regexCmd)
    try
        set capturedData to {}
        set regexResults to do shell script "printf " & inputString & " | " & regexCmd
        set {rocDateString, filename, person} to paragraphs of regexResults
        set capturedData to {rocDateString, filename, person}
    on error
        set capturedData to {"", "", ""}
    end try
    return capturedData
end extractData

BTW, here is the shell version of the command, so you can also test it in the terminal.
% printf "113.1.29 - 一段文字(123)" | sed -E -e 's@^.*/([[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]].*$)@\1@' -e 's@([[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+)[[:blank:]]-[[:blank:]](.*)(\(.*\))@\1\   
\2\  
\3@ ' 


Thanks for the information. The second part of group can include all characters, including Chinese, English, or numbers. That's why I'm using .* at first. Here's some more examples in case you can't type out Chinese on your device. "111.22.1 - test測試(hello)" "113.1.29 - 一段文字(123)"

You have a ? after the last segment (cookie). Does this mean that the string doesn't always end with something in parentheses?

My mistakes. It should always follows the pattern and will sure ends with parenthesis. I have a try catch if regex doesn't match so no need to worry about that part. The main focus is still the Chinese characters that breaks the script. Thanks!

Hey, I just tried out your regex but it only works on sample tests you made. I'm guessing it does not able to capture the actual full path like /Users/username/Desktop/111.11.11 - helloworld(name). Is it because the literal " that breaks this?

I wasn't aware that it was a path being passed to the script. Re quotes… I don't think so. They are necessary for the applescript command and are never seen by the shell. You just need to have part of the pattern string address the remainder of the path. Prefixing ^.* should do that.

Sorry but still i got some problems. Here's the debug info for you. :(
https://imgur.com/a/6udsmoD

Thanks, that helps. I don't think I understood it clearly before.

Apologize for the late reply. This time the script does work indeed. You are the real hero!
